# How do I stop the same question from appearing repeatedly on a flashcard quiz?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

It's a flashcard web application using JavaScript, PHP, and MySQL. It uses 20 URLs of cars and their respective names from a .csv file connected to a database table. The app should be able to bring the image URLs with their names from the database to show as questions with 4 random options for each (one of them is an answer).

1. Questions should appear in a random manner as well as the four answer options.
2. There should a next button, a "Show Answer" Button (Just to see the answer if got it wrong), and a running scorecard.
3. Quiz should restart when page is refreshed and also when one round is finished.
4. A question with the same image URL should not be repeated on a round of 20 questions.

I have written the code and currently facing two problems:

i. Quiz does not restart when the page is refreshed 
ii. Same image appear multiple times in a round of 20 questions.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>

  body  {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #5c94bd;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #474a56;
  padding-top: 1%;

}
 h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-size:1vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font: bold italic;
  }

  img {
    width: 50%;
  }

  div {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  input {
    margin: 5px;
  }

  #picture {
    background-color: #fffdf9;
    -webkit-border-radius: 35px 35px 40px 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 35px 35px 40px 40px;
    border-radius: 35px 35px 40px 40px;
    border: 5px double rgba(28,110,164,0.86);
    border-radius: 35px 35px 40px 40px;
  }

  .correct, .wrong {
  box-shadow: 3px -5px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100%);
  background-color:#ffc477;
  border-radius:28px;
  border:2px solid #eeb44f;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:black;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:1vw;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:italic;
  padding:7px 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0px -3px 0px #cc9f52;
  }

  #show, #next {
  box-shadow:inset 11px 48px 16px -2px #29bbff;
  background-color:#2dabf9;
  border-radius:25px;
  border:5px solid #0b0e07;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:black;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:1vw;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:italic;
  padding:11px 12px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#score, #outOf{
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px 0px #1564ad;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
  background-color:#79bbff;
  border-radius:18px;
  border:1px solid #337bc4;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:black;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:1vw;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:italic;
  padding:12px 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #528ecc;
}

  </style>
  <script>
var answer = "";
  var picNum = 0;
  var score = 0;
  var checked = 0;

  function nextQuestion() {
    localStorage.setItem("picNum", picNum);
    localStorage.setItem("score", score);
    location.reload();
  }

    function showHint() {
      document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "Answer: " + answer;
    checked = 1;
    }

  function endGame() {
    alert("End of Game \nScore: " + score + " out of 20");
  }

  function populate(){
    picNum = localStorage.getItem("picNum");
    score = localStorage.getItem("score");
   if (picNum >= 20){
      endGame();
      picNum = 0;
      score = 0;
    }
    picNum++;
    document.getElementById("outOf").innerHTML = picNum;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
  }

  function checkAnswer(clicked_id){
    if(checked == 0){
      if(clicked_id == "correct"){

        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
        score++;
        alert("Correct!");
      }
      else{
        alert("Wrong Answer. . .! Click Answer button to see the correct answer");
    }

      checked = 1;
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="populate()">
<?php
   $user = "root";
    $pword = "helloworld";
    $dbase = "test";
    $table = "quiz";
       print(" <div class=\"grid\">\n");
       print ("    <div id=\"quiz\">\n");
    print ("  <h2>Hey, how well do you recognize car brands?</h2>\n");
    print ("  <h4>Do you want to give it a try?</h4>\n");
    print ("  <h4>Let's go!</h4>\n");

    $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pword, $dbase);
    if ($mydb->connect_error) {
      die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mydb->connect_error);
    }
    $query = "SELECT name, url FROM $table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4;";
    $result = $mydb->query($query);
    $mydb->close();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    print ("    <img id=\"picture\" src=\"$row[url]\">\n");
    $correct_name = $row["name"];

     print (" <hr style=\"margin-bottom: 5px\">\n");

    print ("  </div>\n");
    print ("    <div>\n");

    $random = rand(0,3);

    for($n = 0; $n < 4; $n++){
        if($random != $n){
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            print ("      <input class=\"wrong\" type=\"button\"  value=\"$row[name]\" onClick=\"checkAnswer(this.id)\">\n");
        }
        else {
            print ("      <input class=\"correct\" type=\"button\" id=\"correct\" value=\"$correct_name\" onClick=\"checkAnswer(this.id)\">\n");
        }
    }


    print ("<script>\n");
    print ("  answer = \"$correct_name\";\n");
    print ("</script>\n");
?>

    </div>
    <div>
      <span id="score">0</span> / <span id="outOf">0</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input id="show" type="button" value="Answer" onClick="showHint()">
      <input id="next" type="button" value="Next" onClick="nextQuestion()">
    </div>
  </form>
  <h2 id="hint"></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome on SO ! Please edit your question. Try to clean your code. It is unreadable and we are not able to reproduce your errors because your code use php. Also, do not ask several questions on the same post. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and as a quick answer, you use local storage so information is not deleted (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Do not store information. And when you click next question, page reloads. So a new call is made to your database and quizz restarts.